# Laravel localization for custom error pages

Tags: laravel, exception, localization, handler

I have custom error pages e.g. resources/views/errors/404.blade.php everything is working just fine but the localization is not working for error pages. If I change website language the error pages still show in default language I tried in many way but its not working, Can anyone please help me make this work thanks in advance.

I try to make it work via exception handler but don't know how to do that. I can apply language middleware is someone can tell me where is default routes for error pages.

Answer (score 1):

Open app/exceptions/handler.php

find render function paste here

don't for get import this trait

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
```

```php
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{

  if($request->hasCookie('language')) {
        // Get cookie
    $cookie = $request->cookie('language');
        // Check if cookie is already decrypted if not decrypt
    $cookie = strlen($cookie) > 2 ? decrypt($cookie) : $cookie;
        // Set locale
    app()->setLocale($cookie);
    }

    if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @Ramil i have done this but the Request::cookie('language') have null value

Answer (score 1):

You can also redirect to other pages in `App\Exceptions\Handler.php`. You can also assign using `App::setLocale()`. Like this:

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    App::setLocale('en_GB');
    /** @var \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Throwable $e */
    $e = $exception;
    $statusCode = $e->getStatusCode();
    return $this->isHttpException($exception) && $statusCode == 404 ?
        response()->view('frontend.pages.404') :
        parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: but i do not want to set locale here instead of that i want to get current locale and want to show error pages in that language

Comment: You can get the current local language with this function: `App::currentLocale()` @AltafHussain

Comment: can i get session locale here

Comment: `App::currentLocale()` returns what the current language is. If you haven't written a method that will automatically trigger `setLocale()` on the value held in the session, you can assign it with `App::setLocale(session('your_key'))`.

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys a little discussion with you guys fixed my problem I get the session's locale value in exception handler that worked for me I am answering it may be can help some one else. Below are the thing I did in App/Exception/Handler.php

```
use Session;

public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    app()->setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

also i moved

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

from web group to global group in kernal.php